# How to check if link is fire from skype and twitter in php

Tags: php, jquery, twitter, skype

I have created referal link, referral link will only work once per ip address, it working fine, the only issue is for skype, and twitter, when we post that link on skype and twitter, it fires it automatically, how can i check the link is fired from skype and twitter, is there anyone who did this with PHP, any help will be really appreciated

Comment: You don't, unless you can get your hands on all Skype and Twitter server IP addresses. And even then it's unreliable because IP addresses are mostly dynamic these days. The reason why this "automaticly" fires is because both Skype and Twitter try to get some extra info, possible a screenshot of the website, to display inside the message. I'd guess this would happen with other social media as well like Facebook for example.

Comment: You could try using `whois` to get IP ranges for Skype and Twitter, but as @icecub says, it won't be 100% reliable. Also, you will probably have to check periodically in case the IP ranges change. You could also try other heuristics like checking the `UserAgent` and `Referer` headers.

Comment: Check the http_referrer in your page. and be careful with ip address It can be forged by vpn